# Test runs on development instead of on TEST environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

`Guard` gem is installed.
When I run test with `bundle exec guard`,and `pry` somewhere within a test scope, `RAILS_ENV` outputs **development** instead of **test**.

So I need to do something like `RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec guard` all the time.

Any ideas to fix this behaviour?

Comment: try to add `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test'` to your `Guardfile`

Comment: but why do you want it? `guard` has nothing with tests or am I missing something?

Comment: I think you should just have `guard 'rspec'` task and `rspec` would run tests with proper ENV. Check guard [examples](https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Guardfile-examples)